# Different positions of an object when it rotates

Tags: word-request

Suppose a stick rotates as shown in the picture, what are called the positions shown with numbers. Or how do you describe these positions by some words? Specially the number 1,

can I say "*the number one is horizontally aligned*"

or maybe just "*the number one is in horizontal position*"?

Moreover, it's not much a formal mathematics question.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking for a term that distinguishes 2 and 4 from all of the others?  Maybe "angled" or "diagonal" or "at 45 degrees".

Comment: You might also need to consider positions 6 and 8, which in terms of slope are the same as 2 and 4 respectively.

Comment: Informally: horizontal, vertical and diagonal might convey the idea. For a more precise explanation I would probably resort to mathematics: specify a centre of rotation and angles of rotation of 45, 90, 135 and 180 degrees.

Comment: @ahmad I'll let you decide but since this looks similar to a circle, those increments look like arcs of a circle. http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/geometry/gp15/circlearcs.htm AND http://www.mathwords.com/a/arc_circle.htm

Comment: @stangdon No, I meant the first one, I modified my question.

Comment: Are we looking at the stick from a top view, like a bird looking down at a flagpost when directly above it (axial rotation)? Or is each of those line segments meant to represent the stick, in each of the positions it can occupy, like a train car on a circular track (revolution)?

Comment: @tromano like a train on a circular track and you are at the right side of this picture seeing the revolution.

Comment: We might well use an analog clock-face for such situations. When the stick is at 12 o'clock, at 1 o'clock, at 2 o'clock, at 3 o'clock, at 4 o'clock... are you limited to an octagon?

Comment: @tromano no its not limmited. I was confused between *horizontally aligned* and *horizontal position* or any other word.

Comment: Are you trying to find  a way to *refer* to those lines in the diagram?  We could refer to lines 1 and 4 as "the horizontal lines", to line   3 is "the vertical line", to lines 2 and 4 as "the slanted lines" or "the oblique lines". There is no need to say "horizontally aligned".  All assuming the page is the frame of reference, of course. But if you're trying to refer to the real-world thing the diagram is supposed to represent, things get more complicated.

Comment: @tromano I see, I decided to use a figure to convey my meaning better, but it seems it was a bit misleading even though I used the *stick* word. I meant for real objects horizontal with ground. But it seems horizontal is ok .

Comment: @djna has the most sensible idea: angles of rotation around the circle's center, with the center of each segment as its reference point. Thus, 1 has position 0°, 2 has position 45°, 3 has position 90°, etc. This will serve as long as each segment is of equal length, and has the advantage that it allows for any segment size: e.g., if the segments are half as long, the positions increase in 22.5° increments.

Answer (score 1):

Number 1 can be called flat, horizontal, or 'laying down'. You can also refer to it as the one on top.

Number 3 would similarly be called upright, vertical, or 'standing up'.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to know with precision exactly where these intermediate positions are, you could refer to them as just that - 'intermediate positions'. Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, however I meant more the number one position

Answer (score 0):

The positions could be described by the points of the compass. Going clockwise : North, North-East, East, South-East, South, etc.

If there were 12 sticks you could use the clock positions : 1 o'clock, 2 o'clock, etc.

Answer (score 0):

- "Number one is in the north position."
- "Number two is is in the northeast position.

or

- "Number one is on top."
- "Number two is in the upper right".